# Remember Me WebSecurity.Login

Tags: remember-me

I am developing a web application in MVC4 and the login view has option remember me - to implement this functionality I am using the cookie created by -

```
WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)
```

Login method as below

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult Login()
   {       //Get persistant cookie
     HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]; 
     if (!ReferenceEquals(authCookie, null))
     {      //Decrypt
         FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value); 
          string userName = Server.HtmlEncode(ticket.Name); //GetuserName
          // get Role and redirect in  as done after authentication
               return RedirectToDefaultView(returnUrl, userName); 
      }
            return View();
}
```

Well I have some concerns - if this is best practice, as I am just verifying the Cookie and if it exists on client machine I am calling method RedirectToDefaultView(returnUrl, userName), which is called after WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe) in 
below method..

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{ 
    if(WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
          return RedirectToDefaultView(returnUrl, userName); 
}
```

The approach I opted after unable to persist the password in login control for some reason, and also read on sites it's not good practice .

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "password-icon", @maxlength = 30 })
```

Any suggestion or help on this would be of gr8 help.

Thanks 
HSR.